# How to Draw this Method of Disk for Shell Revolution?

Tags: tikz-pgf

this is my question -> how to draw this:

[image: goodoldays]

I have this MWE it is a disk, just need to change into a cylindrical shell:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,>=latex,x=1.5cm,y=0.8cm]
        \fill[fill=white,opacity=0.5] (1,0) -- plot[domain=1:4] (\x,{sqrt(2*(\x)+1))}) -- (4,0);
        \fill[fill=white,opacity=0.5] (1,0) -- plot[domain=1:4] (\x,{-sqrt(2*(\x)+1))}) -- (4,0);
        \draw[-,thick,domain=-.2:4.5,samples=100] plot (\x,\x) node[right] {\footnotesize $y=f(x)$};
        \draw[-,thick,domain=-.2:4.5,samples=100] plot (\x,-\x);
        \draw[fill=blue!40] (2.3,0) circle [x radius =.2 , y radius =2.449489743];
        \fill[blue!40] (2.3,-2.449489743) rectangle (2.7,2.449489743);
        \draw[fill=blue!40] (2.7,0) circle [x radius =.2 , y radius =2.449489743];
        \draw (2.3,2.449489743) -- (2.7,2.449489743);
        \draw (2.3,-2.449489743) -- (2.7,-2.449489743);
        \draw[<->] (2.3,-2.6) -- (2.7,-2.6) node[below, midway] {\footnotesize $\Delta x$};
        \draw[<->] (2.9,0) -- (2.9,2.449489743) node[right, midway]  {\footnotesize $R$};
        \draw[->,thick] (-1,0) -- (5,0) node[above] {\footnotesize $x$};
        \draw[->,thick] (0,-5) -- (0,5) node[below right]{\footnotesize $y$};
        \draw[-] (1,3pt) -- (1,-3pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $a$};
        \draw[-] (4,3pt) -- (4,-3pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $b$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: yes]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this I'd choose 2d and the only problem will be to find the tangent points between the cone generatrices and its base (an ellipse in perspective). To find these points we'll need a little bit of trigonometry (see below).

For now, my example:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\newcommand{\ellipsebaratio}{3} % b/a ratio for the ellipse

\tikzset
{% styles
   cylinder inner/.style={thick,draw=blue,top color=blue!40,bottom color=cyan!20},
   cylinder outer/.style={thick,draw=blue,top color=cyan!20,bottom color=blue!40},
   cylinder side/.style={thick,draw=blue,fill=cyan!40},
   cone outer/.style={thick,red!60,top color=red,bottom color=gray,fill opacity=0.25},
   cone inner/.style={thick,red!60,top color=gray!40,bottom color=red!40},
   axis/.style={ultra thick,line cap=butt},
   dimension/.style={latex-latex}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,scale=0.3,
                    yscale=\ellipsebaratio
                   ]
% dimensions
\def\ca{10}   % cone angle
\def\cr{4}    % cone radius
\def\co{2}    % cylinder outer radius
\def\ci{1.5}  % cylinder inner radius
\pgfmathsetmacro\ch{\cr/sin(\ca)}     % cone height
\pgfmathsetmacro\gn{\cr/tan(\ca)}     % cone generatrix
\pgfmathsetmacro\cy{\ch-\co/sin(\ca)} % cylinder height
% cone and axis (first part)
\draw[cone inner] (0,0) -- (\ca:\gn) arc (90+\ca:-90-\ca:\cr) -- cycle;
\draw[axis]      (-2,0) -- (\ch-\cy,0);
% cylinder
\fill[cylinder side,even odd rule] (\ch,0) circle (\co) (\ch,0) circle (\ci);
\draw[cylinder outer] (\ch,0) ++ (0,\co) -- (\cy,\co) arc (90:270:\co) -- (\ch,-\co) arc (270:90:\co);
\draw[cylinder inner] (\ch,0) circle (\ci);
% cone and axis (second part)
\draw[cone outer] (0,0) -- (\ca:\gn) arc (90+\ca:270-\ca:\cr) -- cycle;
\draw[axis] (\ch-\ci,0) -- (\ch+10,0);
% annotations
\foreach\i in {0,\cy}
  \draw (\ch-\i,-\co) --++ (0,-3);
\draw   (\ch,\co)     --++ (3*\ellipsebaratio,0);
\draw[dimension]          (\ch-\cy,-\co-2.75) --++ (\cy,0) node[midway,below] {$\Delta x$};
\draw[dimension] (\ch+2.75*\ellipsebaratio,0) --++ (0,\co) node[midway,right] {$R$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**The Maths**

Let's suppose that we see the cone base as a circle, and we need to find the tangent points in this case. More precisely we know the radius `r` and the angle `alpha` and we want to compute the height `h` and the genereatrix `g`. This is easy, as it's shown in the following figure.

[image]

But, you'll say, the perspective in this figure is all wrong. Yes, but now this is easy to fix. We only need to change the scale for only one of the axes. For example the y-axis. This is in the code at the line

```
yscale=\ellipsebaratio
```

If you comment that line you will get a wrong perspective not very different from the one seen in the second figure. But the new y-scale deforms the circles and turns them into ellipses. And that's just what we need.

Comment: Very very nice. I Will do another my drawing because the Lines not are tangenti to the cylinder.+1

Comment: Beautiful, I love the Maths explanation too, so I can learn the reason why we write such Tikz code

Answer (score 6):

Created with my hands using [Mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/editor).

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\tikzset {_iowdg6aaj/.code = {\pgfsetadditionalshadetransform{ \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{-198 bp } { 158.4 bp }  }  \pgftransformscale{1.32 }  }}}
\pgfdeclareradialshading{_il0gy1303}{\pgfpoint{160bp}{-128bp}}{rgb(0bp)=(1,1,1);
rgb(0bp)=(1,1,1);
rgb(25bp)=(0.41,0.82,0.97);
rgb(400bp)=(0.41,0.82,0.97)}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,416); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 416

%Shape: Can [id:dp7658281586952849] 
\path  [shading=_il0gy1303,_iowdg6aaj] (312.3,238) -- (189.03,238) .. controls (173.29,238) and (160.53,203.26) .. (160.53,160.4) .. controls (160.53,117.54) and (173.29,82.8) .. (189.03,82.8) -- (312.3,82.8) .. controls (328.04,82.8) and (340.8,117.54) .. (340.8,160.4) .. controls (340.8,203.26) and (328.04,238) .. (312.3,238) .. controls (296.56,238) and (283.8,203.26) .. (283.8,160.4) .. controls (283.8,117.54) and (296.56,82.8) .. (312.3,82.8) ; % for fading 
 \draw   (312.3,238) -- (189.03,238) .. controls (173.29,238) and (160.53,203.26) .. (160.53,160.4) .. controls (160.53,117.54) and (173.29,82.8) .. (189.03,82.8) -- (312.3,82.8) .. controls (328.04,82.8) and (340.8,117.54) .. (340.8,160.4) .. controls (340.8,203.26) and (328.04,238) .. (312.3,238) .. controls (296.56,238) and (283.8,203.26) .. (283.8,160.4) .. controls (283.8,117.54) and (296.56,82.8) .. (312.3,82.8) ; % for border 

%Straight Lines [id:da2688155304234523] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 105; green, 208; blue, 248 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (311.75,300.8) -- (33.8,163) ;
%Shape: Donut [id:dp4325332399123063] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 105; green, 208; blue, 248 }  ,fill opacity=1 ,even odd rule] (293.8,160.4) .. controls (293.8,123.34) and (301.97,93.3) .. (312.05,93.3) .. controls (322.13,93.3) and (330.3,123.34) .. (330.3,160.4) .. controls (330.3,197.46) and (322.13,227.5) .. (312.05,227.5) .. controls (301.97,227.5) and (293.8,197.46) .. (293.8,160.4)(283.3,160.4) .. controls (283.3,117.54) and (296.17,82.8) .. (312.05,82.8) .. controls (327.93,82.8) and (340.8,117.54) .. (340.8,160.4) .. controls (340.8,203.26) and (327.93,238) .. (312.05,238) .. controls (296.17,238) and (283.3,203.26) .. (283.3,160.4) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da22040826951195158] 
\draw    (312.05,162.4) -- (417.1,163) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da8600072710761881] 
\draw    (33.8,163) -- (160.53,162.4) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da4150513426865641] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 105; green, 208; blue, 248 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (33.8,163) -- (309.8,17.8) ;
%Shape: Ellipse [id:dp8521303793758079] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 105; green, 208; blue, 248 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (311.75,17.8) .. controls (336.02,17.8) and (355.7,81.15) .. (355.7,159.3) .. controls (355.7,237.45) and (336.02,300.8) .. (311.75,300.8) .. controls (287.48,300.8) and (267.8,237.45) .. (267.8,159.3) .. controls (267.8,81.15) and (287.48,17.8) .. (311.75,17.8) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da4880586858406528] 
\draw    (185.03,344.8) -- (307.53,344.8) ;
\draw [shift={(309.53,344.8)}, rotate = 180] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (12,-3) -- (0,0) -- (12,3) -- cycle    ;
\draw [shift={(183.03,344.8)}, rotate = 0] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (12,-3) -- (0,0) -- (12,3) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da23822019387639726] 
\draw    (417.1,161) -- (417.1,85.8) ;
\draw [shift={(417.1,83.8)}, rotate = 90] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (12,-3) -- (0,0) -- (12,3) -- cycle    ;
\draw [shift={(417.1,163)}, rotate = 270] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (12,-3) -- (0,0) -- (12,3) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da3635008874540595] 
\draw    (312.05,82.8) -- (417.1,82.8) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da11606673988810434] 
\draw    (183.03,238) -- (183.03,344.8) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da8461071359270795] 
\draw    (312.05,162.4) -- (312.05,347.8) ;

% Text Node
\draw (231,323.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\Delta x$};
% Text Node
\draw (424,115.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$R$};


\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Much better now!!! +1

Comment: @JuanCastaño Grazieeeeee \infty

Comment: Great.. Grazie Mille. Anyway Matcha is a Japanese tea

Comment: @FreyatheGoddess Ah ahah..you're welcome ...I like the tea :-)